# Convolver node in AudioGraph (UWP)

Tags: .net, audio, uwp

I'm trying to implement several types of reverberation effect (Hall, Room, Chamber). But I can not find a convolver node in UWP AudioGraph. Is there any analogue of it or maybe there is other way to apply impulse response to the audio buffer?

Comment: Hi there, any update? Does my answer solve your problem? Is it an acceptable answer?

Answer (score 0):

To implement reverberation effect in UWP, we can take advantage of [**ReverbEffectDefinition class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn914313).

This class represents a reverberation effect definition supported by the audio graph. You can demonstrate different types of reverberation effect by setting different values of [ReverbEffectDefinition's properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn914313#properties). For more info about these properties' explanations, please refer to [the MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.xaudio2.xaudio2fx_reverb_parameters(v=vs.85).aspx).

Once the effects are initialized, we can add them to the **EffectDefinitions** list of an audio graph node such as adding to the [EffectDefinitions property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.audio.audiofileinputnode.effectdefinitions) of [AudioFileInputNode class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.audio.audiofileinputnode.aspx) and then apply the reverberation effect by calling [EnableEffectsByDefinition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.audio.audiofileinputnode.enableeffectsbydefinition.aspx) method. For more info, please refer to the [**AudioGraph sample**](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AudioCreation) especially **Scenario 5: In-box Effects**. And the article [Custom audio effects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/custom-audio-effects) also might be helpful.